# Custom query within JPA server-managed session

Tags: jdbc, jta, websphere-liberty, jpa-2.1, jdk6

I'm trying to execute an **unrelated** query (other_table) within a JTA session (server-managed) in order to do some validations, before persisting the bean EJB into DB with JPA.

Here is what I want to do (aprox):

```
@PersistenceUnit(unitName="DynamicDatabase")
EntityManagerFactory emf;

@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED)
private long nextEntryid() {
    em = emf.createEntityManager();
    Query query = em.createQuery("select t from OTHER_TABLE t");
    // do some validation and checking
    MyTable bean = new MyTable();
    em.persist(bean);
}
```

However I keep getting a server error, it does not allow to interact with other database items that are not persisted:

```
org.apache.openjpa.persistence.ArgumentException:
An error occurred while parsing the query filter (query): The name "OTHER_TABLE" is not a recognized entity (...) Perhaps you meant MyTable, which is a close match.

<persistence-unit name="DynamicDatabase" transaction-type="JTA">
    <jta-data-source>jdbc/DB2DynamicConnection</jta-data-source>
    <class>jorge.java.dynamicdatabase.db.MyTable</class>
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

The question is: **what is the proper way to query/alter another table within the same JPA DB connection and JTA transaction?**

Pretty newby about this, please be patient with me. Been working on this very long.

**Edit:** I don't think it's related but FYI I'm using *WebSphere Liberty Profile 8.5.5.4*, JSDK 8u31, EclipseEE Luna 4.4.2 for Web Dev. Going to add it to tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have a @NamedQuery that references the entity `OTHER_TABLE`, and that does not exist or not marked as being an Entity (try in both Java class and persistence.xml).

If the `OtherTable` Java class is not an entity and if it MUST remain so, then you could use [Constructors in JPQL-queries](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/JPQL#Constructors):

```
SELECT NEW com.domain.reports.MyReport(u.firstName, u.lastName, u.birthday) FROM User u
```

If you need to write plain SQL queries, then you could do it using [native queries](https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Basic_JPA_Development/Querying/Native), as they are known in the JPA specification.

Comment: sorry but that's the point --  I want to query something else directly that isn't (or can't be) managed by Java persistence,  AND the query must be run inside the same DB transaction.

Comment: Your answer gave me an idea, and looking more deeply I guess that the function "javax.persistence.EntityManager.createQuery(String)" obviously requires an Entity, which means, it can't be used for something else different. I'll post my answer as soon as my code works.

Comment: If you really understand what an Entity is and if you are sure that `OTHER_TABLE` is not an entity, then you can take a look at [Constructors in JPQL-queries](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/JPQL#Constructors)

Comment: That's a very interesting answer my friend, wow, I'll give it +1 because many people will use it for sure. However for the final solution I'd like to be more generic/universal about an "unrelated query". My real example is much more complicated, and I can't handle it from any Java objects, etc.

Comment: Since my real query is different (related with sequences, etc), so I have chosen the Native Query solution, and it worked great!

Answer (score 0):

Based on Andrei's suggestion, the JPQL (Java Persistence Query Language) operates on objects, not on tables. This means that `em.createQuery()` can't be used for universal database interaction.

To execute any SQL statement generally speaking (inside the container-managed transaction JTA), it is necessary to get the DB connection from the entity manager (it will return the persistence context unit JPA).

```
    // Get container's objects
    em = emf.createEntityManager();
    java.sql.Connection conn = em.unwrap(java.sql.Connection.class);

    // Run the query
    Statement sql = conn.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs = sql.executeQuery("select * from OTHER_TABLE");
    rs.next()
    (...)

    //Container-managed connection shouldn't be closed. 
    rs.close;
    sql.close;
```

Notice that `unwrap` call works for JPA but not for Hibernate (other questions already exist on this point). Notice the different language used for the SQL statement `select * from` than a named query JPQL `select t from`. Exception handling must be also controlled as usual with a `} finally {` clause.

That way would allow to **execute a complex custom statement within server-managed transaction without using JAVA entities** and I can finally sleep.

Comment: There is a betted solution then this: [native queries](https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Basic_JPA_Development/Querying/Native)

Comment: Hello @AndreiI , could you send that comment as an answer so I can mark it as solution (green check)?

Comment: I have added the part with "native queries" to my answer.